# Why would overheating relays cause problems when trying to start a car?

Tags: honda, starting, civic, relay

I have a 2005 Honda Civic. At some point in the last 6 months, I have had trouble starting it (intermittently). It would crank as long as I tried, but the car won't start. Most occurrences occur when I try to start the car after recently stopping it (e.g. stopping for gas).

When I brought it in to get it checked out, the mechanic told me it was because the relays were heating up.

I did some searching around car starting and relays, but I can't seem to piece it together. My understanding is that relays electrical switches, but shouldn't the relays be working for a car to crank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honda had a pretty big problem with their relays. Once the interior of the vehicle heated up, the small circuit board in the relay would expand and the tracings on the board would open enough to cause a no start. Leave the car and let it cool and it would contract and get contact again. Fix is to solder a jumper wire or just replace with an updated relay.