# Why might replacing the relays defer a startup problem for a few weeks?

Tags: honda, starting, civic, relay

I have a 2005 Honda Civic. At some point in the last 6 months, I have had trouble starting it (intermittently). It would crank as long as I tried, but the car won't start. Most occurrences occur when I try to start the car after recently stopping it (e.g. stopping for gas). I can reliably replicate this by waiting 5 minutes in the driveway when I get home, and then try to start the car.

The [relays were replaced a few weeks ago](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/67681/why-would-overheating-relays-cause-problems-when-trying-to-start-a-car), and it seemed to fix the issue for a bit, but the problem came back recently. There seemed to be a progression of things slowly getting worse as it takes one or two more cranks to start until it won't start. The mechanic can't seem to find any other issues.

Why might replacing the relays temporarily fix this issue, and what might the actual cause be?

Comment: Have you checked your fuel pressure? This seems like it may be a typical problem with the fuel pump. When a fuel pump is going out, once they get warmed up, they will sometimes not work. Once they cool back down, they will work again. The only way to see if it's the issue is to put a fuel pressure gauge on the fuel rail and check the pressure when this is happening.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Thanks. I just followed up with the mechanic about this. My car doesn't seem to have any issues while I am driving it, so it didn't seem like it might be the issue. However, we added it to the list of things to check for during my next appointment just in case.

Comment: Hondas are known for heat related no starts when they age. Is it possible the weather was cooler the week it started reliably and now that it is warm again the problem returned?